# Formatting two colum header to a knitr document

Tags: tables, xetex, knitr

I have a report that will be generated as part of a shiny application. Basically a PDF version of the shiny dashboard. There is a specific piece I need to add to the header of the report. It consists of 4 lines of text surrounded by a box (flushed to the left) and a logo(flushed to the right) on the same line/space at the top of the report. It should look like this (example):

[image: header]

I don't actually have code to do this yet. The existing header is in a Word document that has been used, I am trying to automate this process. I have tried various combinations of `\tablular`, `\tabularx` and other things. My first idea was to make a table, full page width, that had each piece - the text in the first column and the logo in the 2nd column. However, getting multiple lines in that first column and a box around it, has proven challenging for me.

Since this is basically a knitr / RMarkdown (.Rmd) document, I am using a `header.tex` file that I include in my preamble. Here is the `header.tex` contents:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\colorlet{lightred}{red!30}
\colorlet{lightyellow}{yellow!30}
\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{{\sethlcolor{lightred}\hl{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlyellow}[1]{{\sethlcolor{lightyellow}\hl{#1}}}
\newcommand{\graph}[3]{
\raisebox{-#1mm}{\includegraphics[height=#2em]{#3}}
}
\usepackage{titling}
%\setlength{\droptitle}{10pt}
\pretitle{
    \begin{flushleft}
        Text
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{logo.png}\\[\bigskipamount]
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
```

My preamble / yaml on the knitr document is fairly standard:

```
---
title: "Title
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
mainfont: Verdana
fontsize: 11pt
linkcolor: blue
geometry: margin=.75in
---
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do, that need the `array` package to use `m` columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}}
\cline{1-1}
Bla bla  \newline Bla \newline Bla \newline bla \newline ...
&  \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image}\\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry this took me so long, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the great solution!